# loading spinner stuck while rendering

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spinner, single-page-application

I have an SPA written mostly with angularJS.
when switching between tabs i have an ng-repeat activated which generates a lot of high-charts on that tab.

the rendering of all these high-charts (containing a large amount of information) takes between 5-40 seconds, depending on the search data.

this is the directive for the spinner:

```
Directives.directive('Loader', function () {
return {
    template: '\
    <div class="row animated fadeIn" ng-if="showLoading" style="margin-top:30px;">\
        <div class="col-md-12" style="text-align:center">\
            <img src="Content/Images/spinLoader.gif" />\
        </div>\
    </div>'
};
});
```

so that the directive listens to `showLoading` in order to activate the spinner or turn it off.

when starting the rendering in each tab I give `showLoading` the value true and I've added an `onLoad` attribute to the high-charts so that it gives `showLoading` the value false when finishing the rendering like this:

```
                chart: {
                    type: 'boxplot',
                    zoomType: 'xy',
                    //width: 580,
                    //height: 340

                    events: {
                        load: function () {

                            $scope.showLoading = false;
                        }
                    }

                },
```

the issue is that while rendering all of the high-charts, the spinner is kinda stuck and does not spin.

Of course the whole idea of putting the spinner there is to show the user that the app isn't stuck, and the current situation sort of causes the user to think it is stuck.

just to be clear, the gif does spin up until the point that the high-charts start showing - which means the point from where the charts are shown empty till the point where the rendering has finished

ideas would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned in your question that you are generating lot of high-charts within tabs using ng-repeat.

ng-repeat would iterate over given list of items and all high-charts loading initiate immediately. Loading large amount data may freeze the browser and perhaps due to which spinner doesn't work as expected.

Instead of ng-repeat, I suggest to use Lazy loading technique to load large amount of dataset. Split overall high-charts which are required to be loaded into appropriate task

**Example:** Assume you have 10 high-charts to be loaded within the tab. Based the level of their data structure and complexity split the loading of these charts in 3 or 4 steps.

- Step 1: -Show Spinner - Load 3 high-charts, once finished
- Step 2: Load 3 more Charts, once finished
- Step 2: Load 4 Charts, hide spinner